# How to format the csv table?

Tags: python, csv

I have some code, written in Python, that should save some data in a list. This list should be saved in a `csv` table. But now there is the problem. I want to have a format like:

```
word#1;1
word#2;0
word#3;1
```

and so on.

I would like to have this format, but there are three problems.

1. Between the letters is always a space.
2. The 1 and the word aren't in one column, 
   so the word is in column 1 and the number in column 2
3. For the number 1, in the column is written: 01, but for 0 is written: 0

Code:

```py
    import csv
    with open('train.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile,
                                quotechar='', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        x3 = len(fertig)
        while i < x3:
            spamwriter.writerow(fertig[i])
            i = i + 1
            if i == x3:
                break
```

`Fertig` is a list, wrote like this:

```
Fertig = ([word#1;1,word#2;0])
```

So, and I want to have this in a csv Table, every word#x;1(or 0) in one row. And this only in one column. I User Excel

Comment: Posting an example of the CSV will help people answer your question.

Comment: Yes; just as SO recommends you post just enough code to reproduce the problem, post a sample of your csv file to help debug the code

Comment: What is `fertig`?

Comment: Fertig is a list, including daraus from a Text file.
Ist like: Fertig = ([ word#1;1,word#2;0)]

Answer (score 0):

You don't show what's in your `fertig` list, so I made a guess.

```
import csv

fertig = [
    ["word#1", 1],
    ["word#2", 0],
    ["word#3", 1],
]

with open('train.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    spamwriter.writerows(fertig)
```

Contents of `train.csv` file afterwords:

```
word#1;1
word#2;0
word#3;1
```